# How to properly configure multiple component scans and "use default filters = false"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, component-scan

I'm developing a "new application" that wants to leverage code in an existing application, but I am having trouble getting "contextLoads()" to pass in the new application.

This configuration doesn't work:

```
//This is the main common library B application class:
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages=["com.acme.cacheb.lib"])
@Import(CacheACommonLibConfig.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties 
class CacheBCommonLib {

}

//This  is the Config class Imported above:
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages=["com.acme.cachea.lib"], 
                             useDefaultFilters = false, 
                             includeFilters = [@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, 
                             value = RescHandshakeTypeFilter.class)])
class CacheACommonLibConfig {

}
```

The error reported is an autowire failure:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheA_RepoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cacheA_Repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.acme.cachea.lib.jpa.repository.ICacheA_Repository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I know my custom filter is matching everything I want (including that "missing" interface named ICacheA_Repository) and nothing I think I don't want.  I suspect the error is because "useDefaultFilters = false" is in play and how the component scans are combined.  If I do this

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages=["com.acme.cacheb.lib", "org.springframework"])
```

in the new main application class, the test runs longer before it fails reporting a different error, and I also get a fairly dire "Spring Warning"

```
** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of 'org.springframework'.
```

Any/All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If `ICacheA_Repository` is a Spring Data JPA repository that won't be detected by a component scan. Spring Data uses its own mechanism to detect repositories.

Comment: If I change "org.springframework" to "org.springframework.data.jpa" in the new app's main class basePackages list, the autowire failure also turns into a different error reported when the "context loads" test fails.  This new error points to NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.<init>()

Comment: @M. Deinum If I completely remove component scanning the "cache A" jar and only scan the new "cache B" app's classpath, "context loads" passes.  Are you saying Spring Data will have found the "Cache A" repositories in the "Cache A" jar anyway through its own detection mechanism?  If so, that's an answer, and maybe this is another question, but how would I validate that fact?  Can I autowire one of the repos or something to prove they are available in the new application's context?

Comment: Why on earth are you scanning `org.springframework`? Don't scan that. Use `@EnableJpaRepositories` and put the package containing your repositories in there, it will then be detected.

Answer (score 0):

I got "context loads" to pass in the B app by abandoning "include filtering" (with use default filters = false) of the A app dependency jar and switching to "exclude filtering" on the component scan.  But after I "actually" got it working, I'm not sure I really needed to switch to "exclude filtering".  The reason I think that is because at the end of my journey, I started seeing the same couple of errors I first saw which is why the "Thymeleaf View Resolver" is now excluded from auto configuration.  (If only I had tried that when the error first appeared, rather than totally disabling auto configuration...)

The B app main class configuration is now configured like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages=["com.acme.cacheb.lib"])
@Import(CacheACommonLibConfig.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=[WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class, ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class])
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EntityScan('com.acme.cacha.lib.jpa.entity')
@EnableJpaRepositories('com.acme.cacha.lib.jpa.repository')
//@EnableScheduling
class CacheBCommonLib {

}
```

and the Imported config class is now configured like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages=["com.acme.cacha.lib.msg.auth",
                         "com.acme.cacha.lib.msg.emp",
                         "com.acme.cacha.lib.msg.processor",
                         "com.acme.cacha.lib.jpa"],
    excludeFilters = [@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, value = CacheBExcludeCacheATypesFilter.class),
                      @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX,
                       pattern = "com.acme.cacha.lib.msg.processor.*"),
                      @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX,
                       pattern = "com.acme.cacha.lib.msg.auth.(sas|radius).*")
                     ])
class CacheACommonLibConfig {

}
```